# I want to remove linkedin connections in Bulk

Tags: javascript, automation, linkedin-j

Long time back i have added 20k people in linkedin. now i want to clean up my list and i only want to add then who i know. i have deleted 10k people manually but its getting annoying i need a javascript
script to do my task automatically. previously my friend wrote a script for me and it worked but since few days its not working. i desperately need help. i will be grateful if you can help.

**I will be responsible if anything happens to my linked in account.
**
previous code that i have:

`setInterval(() =>
{
document.getElementsByClassName("mn-connection-card__dropdown-trigger")[0].click();
document.getElementsByClassName('mn-connection-card__dropdown-option-icon')[0].click();
document.getElementsByClassName('artdeco-button--primary')[0].click();
}, 300)

`

previous code that i have:

`setInterval(() =>
{
document.getElementsByClassName("mn-connection-card__dropdown-trigger")[0].click();
document.getElementsByClassName('mn-connection-card__dropdown-option-icon')[0].click();
document.getElementsByClassName('artdeco-button--primary')[0].click();
}, 300)

`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want to automate the removal of linkedin connects with a js script.